# Disallowing MariaDB query cache except from webserver (JDBC)

Tags: mysql, jdbc, cache

I have an application server (Play Framework), webserver (Caddy), and database server (MariaDB with InnoDB) that are running on a single machine for now.

The database is used in two ways:

- client Python code that makes highly specific SELECTs (over an SSH tunnel).
- the web/application server, which performs *occasional* INSERTs and UPDATEs, but mostly SELECTs from large tables each time a page loads.

Is there a simple way to enable (and force) query caching for the webserver but not for the client code? My thought was to set `query_cache_type=DEMAND` and use `SQL_CACHE` on the webserver, but it's not ideal. Perhaps I can force JDBC to use `SQL_CACHE` somehow?

**Clarification:**
The unfortunate technical issue with adding `SQL_CACHE` to every query is that the web application queries using [Slick](http://slick.lightbend.com/) and a JDBC backend. The integration with Slick is tight so I can't rewrite the application layer, and I don't know how to force JDBC to append `SQL_CACHE`.

Comment: Which role does JDBC play in this scenario? Is it used by the Python client? (My guess is it isn't, and you're connection is using [`mysql.connector`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-example-connecting.html) and JDBC isn't playing a role.)

Comment: @joanolo JDBC is used in the web application server, which is using Play and Slick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is a lot of write activity, the Query Cache is virtually useless -- because *all* QC entries for a table are purged when *any* modification happens to the table.

If the QC is useful, using `query_cache_type=DEMAND` *and* manually saying `SQL_CACHE` or `SQL_NO_CACHE` on every `SELECT` *may* be optimal.  This keeps the rare, bulky, queries from cluttering the cache, while allowing the 'good' ones to make use of the QC.  Note:  This has nothing to do with the connector (JDBC, etc), only with the `SELECT` statements.

Yes, `DEMAND` without `SQL_CACHE` leads to not using the QC.  I agree that this is "not ideal" since it depends on un-obvious rules about the QC.  Still, it may be your best solution, other than...

If a query is slow slow that it matters, we should look critically at the query.  The speed-up may be as simple as adding a 'composite' index, or some seemingly minor tweak to the query such as not hiding an indexed column in a function call (eg, `DATE(dt) = ...`).

Comment: Thanks for the reply! There are very few writes.

The unfortunate technical issue with adding `SQL_CACHE` to every query is that the web application queries using [Slick](http://slick.lightbend.com/) rather than raw SQL.

Comment: I don't know how to force Slick or JDBC, which it uses, to append `SQL_CACHE`, and rewriting most of the application layer to use raw SQL isn't an option at this point.

Comment: Alas, another case of a 3rd party layer getting in the way?